# How to connect from Google App Engine through static IP

Tags: google-app-engine, static-ip-address

We are making application on Google App Engine but it has to connect from static IP address to another service. I'm searching the best way to route traffic through static IP.

I was thinking that the easiest way would be to set up a proxy on Google Compute Engine but maybe someone have better idea.

Have you ever done something like this?
What is the simplest aproach?

Comment: How (if at all) did you eventually solve this? I was thinking exactly along the same path, and I'm now considering implementing a reverse proxy on Google Compute Engine.

Comment: We have set up VM on Compute Engine and used it as a gateway. On this VM we have placed app which comunicates with App Engine and external service

Comment: Same as we have eventually. We set a small machine an Compute Engine with nginx set as a reverse proxy to our App Engine server.

Answer (score 0):

**Node based http / https proxy**

- Get a VPS with an static ip address.
- Install Node JS
- Follow the instruction on this GitHub project and you will have a high performance proxy running in no time.

https://github.com/TellusTalk/Node_Proxy